# Connecting TypeScript to python

Tags: python, typescript

I have tried searching everywhere but to no avail. Can anyone guide me as to how to pass data from typescript to python? The data is such that I will use it to do webscraping using beautifulSoup over in python. As I'm not putting any implementations here, any general guidance will do :)

Comment: Can you clarify more your needs and the technology you want to use

Comment: stackoverflow is better for specific code problems instead of general guidance :) there are so many ways you can solve this!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating an api on python?
I guess you can pass the data from typescript to python using Http in the form of json or just save the file using typescript and read it using python and edit it as you want.

Comment: I see. Can you elaborate on how to pass data using http in the form of json?? Thank you so much :)

Comment: create a Django/Flask/Fast Api server. and use the Post request from TypeScript to your HTTP server